# How can I make this an insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am new to SQL, So I have a table called 'DealerShip' and I have a many different car ID's . I have a dealership called 'Hondo' and another one called 'Mitch' . I would like to insert about 80 records into 'Mitch' that 'Hondo' has . For instance with this Query

```
select * from DealerShips where name='Hondo' and CarType=63
```

That query above contains about 70 records, How can I create an insert statement that will insert all the returned records from that query above ? The insert will go into the same table above except that the name will be 'Mitch' . I am using MSSQL 2012

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT INTO SELECT`

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (FIELDS...)  ---- fields here should match the select fields
SELECT FIELDS... FROM
DealerShips where name = 'Hondo' and CarType=63
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you list the columns in the insert and the select in the same order.

```
INSERT INTO DealerShips (name, cartype, more columns)
SELECT 
    'Mitch'
  , cartype
  , more columns
from DealerShips where name='Hondo' and CarType=63
```